# Objective C - Linked List printing 0s

Tags: objective-c, linked-list

I am making a Linked List in Objective C and it works for the most part. The only issue is that when I print the items from the list, it also prints a 0 after printing each item.

The output of the code is:

5
0
6
0
7

I am trying to figure out why the 0 is showing up and how to stop it. The code is:

**The Node class header file**

```
@interface Node : NSObject {
    NSInteger data;
}

-(id) initWith : (NSInteger) number;

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger getData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Node *nextNode;
```

**The Node class implementation file**

```
-(id) initWith: (NSInteger)number {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        Node *node = [[Node alloc] init];
        self.nextNode = node;
        data = number;
    }

    return self;
}

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // custom initialization
    }

    return self;
}

-(NSInteger)getData {
    return data;
}
```

**The LinkedList header file**

```
@interface LinkedList : NSObject {
    NSInteger data;
}

-(id)initWith : (NSInteger) number;
-(void) insertInteger : (NSInteger) number;
-(void) printList;
```

The LinkedList implementation file

```
@implementation LinkedList
{
    Node *head;
}

-(id)initWith:(NSInteger)number {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        if (head == nil) {
            head = [[Node alloc] initWith:number];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        // custom initialization
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) insertInteger:(NSInteger)number {

    if (head == nil) {
        head = [[Node alloc] initWith:number];
    }
    else {
        // traverse to the end of the linked list
        Node *currentNode = head;

        while (currentNode.nextNode != nil) {
            currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
        }

        // add the item at the end of the list
        Node *insertNode = [[Node alloc] initWith:number];
        [currentNode setNextNode:insertNode];
    }
}

-(void) printList {
    if (head == nil) {
        NSLog(@"List is empty");
    }
    else {
        Node *currentNode = head;
        while (currentNode.nextNode !=nil) {
            NSLog(@"%tu", currentNode.getData);
            currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
        }
    }
}
```

**The main class file**

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    LinkedList *list1 = [[LinkedList alloc] init];
    [list1 insertInteger:5];
    [list1 insertInteger:6];
    [list1 insertInteger:7];

    [list1 printList];

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that every time you create a node, the new node creates yet another node and makes that it's "next" node. Why? Don't create the 2nd node, simply set `nextNode` to `nil`.

So basically you have an extra node between each proper node.

And you need to adjust all of your code to walk the list. For example, printing should be:

```
-(void) printList {
    if (head == nil) {
        NSLog(@"List is empty");
    }
    else {
        Node *currentNode = head;
        while (currentNode) {
            NSLog(@"%tu", currentNode.getData);
            currentNode = currentNode.nextNode;
        }
    }
}
```